# Returning different sub-classes from a function?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3

Say I have four sub-classes of 'Car'. One for each color. I want to have one function that can build and return a 'color-car' sub-class based on the passed value. This is a dumb example, I know, but it is precisely what I am trying to do only on a smaller scale.

```
public class Car
{
}

public class BlueCar extends Car
{
}
```

You get it.

Then, in another (helper) class, I have a function which takes in a string of the color and returns the correct sub-class.

```
public function GetCarFromColor(_color:String):Car
{
    if (_color == "blue")
    {
        var myCar:BlueCar = new BlueCar;
        return myCar;
    } else if (_color == "red")
    {
        var myCar:RedCar = new RedCar;
        return myCar;
    }
```

Ok. You get it. This doesn't work for a reason unknown to me. I get 1118 errors which complain about conversion of BlueCar into Car, etc...

Can someone help me out here? Thanks!

Comment: I wasn't aware you could leave the parentheses off constructor calls in AS3.

Comment: you can, it even saves a few bytes ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try casting your derived class to the base class before returning it back.

Not sure about actionscript but in C++ you could do it like this

Base *GetCarFromColor()
{
    Base *b1;
    b1 = new D1;
    return b1;
}

Comment: Don't know actionscript but implicit upcasting not being implemented seems like a bit of an oversight by the compiler developers.

Comment: Ok. And how would I do that? :)

Comment: Modified my answer to show you how can you do it in C++, may be you dont have pointers in actionscript.

Answer (score 2):

Make the return variable to be of the supertype:

```
public function GetCarFromColor(_color:String):Car
{
    var myCar:Car
    if (_color == "blue")
    {
        myCar = new BlueCar;
        return myCar;
    } else if (_color == "red")
    {
        myCar = new RedCar;
        return myCar;
    }
```

This should now compile ok.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use an interface instead?

```
public interface ICar
{
}

public class BlueCar implements ICar
{
}

public function GetCarFromColor(_color:String):ICar
{
}
```

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't seem to work. Would I still need to cast as suggested above?

Comment: I don't think you would need a cast if you use interfaces.  But you shouldn't need a cast with subclasses either.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you were getting errors is because you have two local variables of the same name with different types in one function:

```
var myCar:BlueCar = new BlueCar;
var myCar:RedCar = new RedCar;
```

The variable `myCar` is typed as both BlueCar and RedCar. In ActionScript 3, variables are always scoped to the entire function. In other languages, like Java, I know that if statements and loops create a new block-level scope, but that's not the case here.

As Matt Allen suggested, typing `myCar` as the superclass, `Car`, should stop these compiler errors.